# react-native - can't access setState inside component function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I'm learning react-native and now I'm stucked on state lesson with this error:

```
_this2.setState is not a function.
```

Here's the current block of code.

```
...
export default class StopWatch extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timeElapsed: null
    }
  }

  handleStartStopClick(){
    var startTime = new Date();

    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(previousState => {
        return {timeElapsed:new Date() - startTime};
      });
    }, 100);
  }
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`handleStartStopClick` is called from a context where `this` is not your class's instance. You can avoid that by adding `.bind(this)` to the function you are passing as your click handler.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleStartStopClick.bind(this)}>
```

Comment: it worked! I was missing the `bind(this)` block! thank you!

Comment: Adding to this, I would recommend you to bind your function in your constructor instead of in onPress. Otherwise, you will bind your function each time the component is re-render and it can result in performance decrease.

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp Definitely, this is the performant way to do it

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
 this.setState({timeElapsed : (new Date() - startTime)})
```

You must defined your function in constructor with ***bind(this)*** or

```
handleStartStopClick = () => {...}
```

Comment: How would using deprecated version of `setState` help?

Comment: I think ,Problem is setState is not function, also it sets one State to another State. Like this:
    this.setState(  state : value you want set )

Comment: Yes. the problem is that `handleStartStopClick` is being called without binding thus having wrong context. So your answer not only doesn't help but promotes deprecated API.

Comment: Okay thank @YuryTarabanko . I have fixed my answer ^^. We can use bind(this) or use direct arrow function in ES 6